# Как реализовать смену картинок поочередно?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Допустим, у меня есть 100 картинок. В zip/просто в папке. Эти картинки должны бы последовательно сменять друг друга, отображаясь в , в идеале без повторений, по нажатию кнопки. Пробовал через создание списка путей и list.pop(), ругается, что такого файла не существует, даже через абсолютный путь, хотя отдельно список и list.pop() работают чудесно, и значения выводят как надо.

Собственно, как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import cycle
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

zip_file = ZipFile('images.zip', 'r')
images = cycle(zip_file.namelist())

def change_image(label):
    with BytesIO(zip_file.read(next(images))) as data:
        with Image.open(data) as img:
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            label.image = photo
            label.configure(image=photo)


root = Tk()
root.title('Demo')

label = Label(root)
label.pack()

button = Button(root, text='Следующая картинка', command=partial(change_image, label))
button.pack()

change_image(label)
root.mainloop()
```